# QApplication static linkage

Tags: windows, qt, static-linking

I build a Main App/plugin application using qt 5.1 for multi platform purpose.

In windows, the Main app is statically linked whereas the plugins are dynamically linked (the first one is a requirement, the second more of a choice :) )

Up until now, everything worked fine.

Now I want the plugin to be able to show some stuff (mostly configuration...) and everything is not working fine on windows. When I intend to show something i got a "QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice". after a little bit of research, i understand that everything relying on a UI must have a instance of QApplication running, so qApp should not be NULL, but it is with my plugins but not my main app.

Anyone knows how to set/assign a QApplication ?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to display widgets from the plugins before calling QApplication::exec. Just make sure that occurs before your plugins try to display any widgets.

Comment: Make sure not to have widgets as static variables constructed on startup. Other possibility is that the central QCoreApplication::instance doesn't return the same instance in main app and plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

discussed it in Qt-project forums and the only way to make it work is to create a QApplication in the plugins when it does not exists (which is only the case when the app it statically linked against Qt)

And I make the plugin also statically linked against Qt too and it works fine :)